# undefined method `strftime' for "{1=>2019, 2=>7, 3=>7, 4=>16, 5=>0}":String Did you mean? strip

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, strftime

I am trying to have the time output in a nice way.
Here is my code in new

```
<%= form_for @reservation do |f| %>
   <span><label>Pick up time</label></span>
     <%= f.time_select :time,ampm: true, class: "textbox"%></span>
<% end %>
```

And here is in the output file

```
<strong>Pick up Time:</strong> <%= @reservation.time.strftime("%H:%M")  %>
```

I got this error 
undefined method `strftime' for "{1=>2019, 2=>7, 3=>7, 4=>16, 5=>0}":String
Did you mean?  strip

Please some one help me to fix this

Comment: What does `@reservation.time` return?

Comment: {1=>2019, 2=>7, 3=>7, 4=>19, 5=>59}

Comment: That looks like a hash. `strftime` is a DateTime method, what's the data type for reservation time in your schema, if any?

Comment: add_column :reservations, :time, :string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sebastian mentions in a comment; it looks as though your `time` object is a Hash. To call `strftime` your object needs to be a `:datetime`.

To fix this you should change the column type in your database to be that of datetime (As well as changing your forms to save a datetime value).

An alternative would be to build the string you want to display manually using what is in `time` (not using strftime).

Comment: Do you know how can I show the am and pm on this? <%= @reservation.time.strftime("%H:%M")  %>

Comment: It's strftime("%I:%M %p")

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only this hash then you need to parse it to date time like below

```
a = {1=>2019, 2=>7, 3=>7, 4=>16, 5=>0}
time = (a.values.first(3).join("/") + " "+ a.values.last(2).join(":")).to_datetime.strftime("%I:%M %p")
```

After parsing to date and time you can perform any method of date time.

Answer (score 0):

```
(@reservation.to_date).strftime("%H:%M")
```

It seems to be an order of operations - first change string to date then transform. Something similar worked for me in Workato just now.